LC filter for ignition noise
I have a low power detection circuit for a truck battery. It detects if the power of the battery is going below 11.8 V and turns off a relay. The circuit worked amazing on the table. When installed on the truck, if I turn ON the truck, the relay starts to go ON and OFF repeatedly and then settles down. This is happening due to the noise from the ignition.

What would be an easy fix? Should I put an LC filter in front of my comparator? Or right before the relay?
I found an online version of designing LC filter.
Not sure how to get the input impedance or output impedance?

What does your noise look like? Do you have an oscope?

Unfortunately, we don't have an oscilloscope. It is on my next to buy list :)

Are you using twisted pair wires? Consider adding  a cap across input +/- p1,p3 for T=RC => 100ms to suppress noise  and maybe add hysteresis with R from out to Vin+ (1M to 10M)  L is not necessary.

Ok, I can try that.

Note also that 11.8V is a very tight tolerance on a good 12.6V battery voltage. Just from voltage drop in the cables. Just by running the starter motor I wouldn't be surprised if the voltage actually drops below 11.8 V - never mind the positive pulse from ignition noise

Filtering ignition noise is a big challenge. Here is one example of typical signal.
Note the trigger is set at 102V, and the rigning voltage drops to nearly zero:

For more results, Google search for [scope trace of ignition noise when starting car], you will be impressed.
I would think a simple LC with any heavy capacitor or inductor will not fix this kind of signaling, unless you completely mask/block the entire transient.

Give the comparetor some hysteresis by placing some megohms between pin 1 and 4 ,now RC filter on VR1 and check the drawing around VR1 .Also filter your 12 Volts to the chip with say 100 ohm and 1uF with a 15Volt 1 watt zener across the 1 uF cap.This stops noise getting into the chip.

Why not use the RC filtered power to run the comparator?
